# Respectable-abbreviations macro

Tags: macros

How might one write a macro that makes slovenly abbreviations respectable?

```
\documentclass{article}
% \newcommand\abr{...}
\begin{document}
I've seen it in the \abr{OED}.
\end{document}
```

What I mean is that `OED` should be rendered as `O.\,E.\,D.`.

As Mico points out, there should never be two contiguous points.  I
suppose one might use `\@ifnextchar.` to prevent that.

Comment: Are you sure that you want two `.` punctuation marks after the (non-slovenly) version of `OED`?

Comment: @Mico, I'm sure I don't; edited.

Comment: Note however that the norm is that abbreviations should be typeset without any dots. I don't have the reference to the norm right now, but I'll post it later on.

Answer (score 7):

All in all the same as the answer by Steven B. Segletes, but expandable. Also almost everything as contents should be fine (except the really unlikely `\endabr@`).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\abr[1]
  {%
    \abr@#1\endabr@
  }
\def\abr@#1#2\endabr@
  {%
    #1.%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      \@%
      \expandafter\@gobble
    \else
      \,%
      \expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
    {\abr@#2\endabr@}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Single letter:
\abr{eg}

Multi letter: 
\abr{{th}e}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe mine is fully expandable, as well.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\def` is not expandable.

Comment: Got it.  I meant to say, mine can be placed in an `\edef`.  But you are right, the contents of the `\edef` are not the final expansion.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It can't be placed inside an `\edef` as the `\edef` would try to expand `\next` before it gets defined.

Comment: It can too be placed in an `\edef`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no. Just try `\edef\tmp{\abr{OED}}` right after the definition of `\abr` and `\abraux` in your MWE. It'll throw an error.

Comment: `\edef\tmp{\abr{OED}} \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}` yields `O.\def \spacefactor \@m {}{\protect \relax \kern .16667em E.\def \space-
factor \@m {}{\protect \relax \kern .16667em D.\def \spacefactor \@m {}{\space-
factor \@m {}}\spacefactor \@m {}}\spacefactor \@m {}}\spacefactor \@m
{}\relax`.  This typesets as `O.\,E.\,D.\@`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the simplest form of my original approach.  It can be placed in an `\edef`.  Its only drawback is that it can blow the stack if the argument is too long (maybe 256 characters??)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\abr[1]{\abraux#1\relax\relax}
\def\abraux#1#2\relax{#1.\ifx\relax#2\relax\@\else\,\abraux#2\relax\fi}
\begin{document}
Here is \abr{OED} abbreviation.

Here is \abr{XO} abbreviation.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If that really were an issue, here is an alternative that doesn't have that problem.

There seems to be a misunderstanding that this definition of `\abr` cannot be placed into an `\edef`.  It can.  Naturally, the expansion is not necessarily pretty, but it will yield the proper typesetting.  The only proviso is that `\@MyOwnMacro` is not used elsewhere in your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\let\@MyOwnMacro\relax
\newcommand\abr[1]{\abraux#1\relax\relax}
\def\abraux#1#2\relax{%
  #1.\ifx\relax#2\relax\def\@MyOwnMacro{\@}\else\def\@MyOwnMacro{\,\abraux#2\relax}\fi%
  \@MyOwnMacro%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is \abr{OED} abbreviation.

Here is \abr{XO} abbreviation.

Can be edef'ed:

\edef\tmp{\abr{OED}} \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}

expands to \tmp
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers to you :-) for your good solution. I have removed my comment. Is it correct in English language?

Comment: @Sebastiano 5:5 (loud and clear).  Excellent English. Saluti!

Comment: It can't be `\edef`ed if it is used for the first time! It'll throw an error.

Comment: @Skillmon OK, `\let\next\relax` fixes that.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes as soon as anything else uses `\next` you'll get problems. In general your macro can't be fully expandable as long as it contains anything changing the definition of anything.

Comment: @Skillmon Well, there is certainly an argument to be made for naming it `\@MyOwnSpecialMacro` rather than `\next`.

Comment: It still can't be placed inside of an `\edef`. Look at the results. You're redefining `\spacefactor`. Put a `\texttt{\meaning\spacefactor}` after your `expands to \tmp`. It is dangerous to put it into an `\edef`. You should define `\abraux` with `\protected\def\abraux#1#2\relax`. Or even better, define `\abr` protected.

Comment: Note that mine isn't fully expandable, too, as `\@` isn't.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

- Cases such as `\abr{OED}` or `\abr{IMF}` work just as expected. If the acronym contains both uppercase and lowercase letters, dots are inserted only before the uppercase letters in the interior of the acronym. E.g., `\abr{MSc}` generates `M.\,Sc.`, and `\abr{PhD}` generates `Ph.\,D.`.
- It can handle mixed-case acronyms such as "PhD" directly -- no need to write `\abr{{Ph}D}`.
- If a "slovenly abbreviation" *ends* a sentence, one should place the "." punctuation mark inside the argument of `\abr`. The code takes care to insert a `\@` "space factor* directive before the final `.` character. This, in turn, informs LaTeX that that `.` character should be treated as ending a sentence.
- The code returns nothing if the argument of `\abr` is either empty or expands to return nothing. E.g., `\def\ttt{} /\abr{\ttt}/` returns `//`. If the code encounters non-letter characters -- say, `(` and `)` -- no periods are inserted before or after them.
- The code is expandable in the sense that `\abr` can be included in the argument of an `\edef` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}   % for 'luacode' environment

%% Lua-side code:
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function abr ( s )
  n = string.len ( s )
  -- Do nothing unless "s" is non-empty.
  if n>0 then 
    s_mod = ""  -- initialize the string

    -- Process the first n-1 characters in "s"
    for i=1, n-1 do
      s12 = string.sub ( s  , i, i+1 )
      s1  = string.sub ( s12, 1, 1 )
      if string.match ( s12 , "%a%u" ) then
        s_mod = s_mod .. s1 .. ".\\,"
      else
        s_mod = s_mod .. s1
      end
    end

    -- Process the final character in "s"
    s_n = string.sub ( s , n)
    if     string.match (s_n, "%.") then   -- "." char.
      s_mod = s_mod .. "\\@." 
    elseif string.match (s_n, "%l") then   -- lowercase letter
      s_mod = s_mod .. s_n .. ".\\hbox{}"
    elseif string.match (s_n, "%u") then   -- uppercase letter
      s_mod = s_mod .. s_n .. "."
    else                    -- Any other character:
      s_mod = s_mod .. s_n  -- don't add anything after 's_n'
    end
```

```tex
    -- Print the modified string
    tex.sprint ( s_mod )
  end
end

\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code: macro that calls the Lua function
\newcommand\abr[2]{\directlua{abr("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\abr{OED}, \abr{PhD}, \abr{DPhil}, \abr{MSc}, \abr{()}

\smallskip
% Two calls to "\abr" with an empty argument (upon expansion):
.\abr{}. \quad 
\def\ttt{} .\abr{\ttt}. 

\bigskip
\edef\tmp{\abr{MA}}   \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}

\edef\tmp{\abr{MA.}}  \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}

expands to: \tmp

\smallskip
\edef\tmp{\abr{MSc}}  \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}

\edef\tmp{\abr{MSc.}} \detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}

expands to: \tmp

\bigskip
Some tests of spacing after punctuation marks:

\smallskip
a \abr{PhD} candidate --- good

a Ph.\,D. candidate   --- just to verify

\smallskip
an \abr{MSc} candidate --- good

an M.\,Sc.\ candidate  --- just to verify

\smallskip
She has a \abr{PhD.} So do I. --- good

She has a Ph.\,D\@.  So do I. --- just to verify

\smallskip
He has an \abr{MSc.} So do I. --- good

He has an M.\,Sc.    So do I.  --- just to verify

\smallskip
Does he have an \abr{MSc.}? Really?! --- good

Does he have an M.\,Sc.?    Really?!  --- just to verify
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder if it weren't more correct to put a sentence-ending point after the macro rather than into the argument, seeing as the full-stop is not part of the abbreviation.

Comment: @Toothrot - A major issue is: How does one inform LaTeX whether a sentence ends with a slovenly abbreviation? If one writes `I like the \abr{OED}.`, one ends up with two "dots" -- not good. The only way I can think of indicating reliably to LaTeX that a sentence ends right after some `\abr{...}` directive is to include the period in the argument of `\abr`. I've come up with an update to the code that allows `\abbr{MSc}` and `\abr{MSc.}` to be typeset differently. I'll post the updated code shortly.

Comment: How about `\@ifnextchar.{\spacefactor3000\@gobble}` or something like that?

Comment: @Toothrot - Using `\@ifnextchar` is a potentially interesting idea. I'll have to think about some more; unfortunately, I won't be able to get to work on it until this evening at the earliest. Maybe somebody else will come up with a good solution in the meantime...

Answer (score 5):

Let TeX do the recursion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify{\,} % just in order it doesn't expand in \edef

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\abr}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_function:fN { \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -2 } } \__toothrot_abr:n
  \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { -1 } { -1 } .
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_function:nN { f }
\cs_new:Nn \__toothrot_abr:n { #1.\, }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\abr{OED}

\abr{{Ph}D}

\edef\test{\abr{OED}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\edef\test{\abr{}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

If a part of the argument is braced, it is considered as a single item.

One might check whether the argument is empty in order to print nothing at all, but it doesn't seem so important a feature.

[image]

With `\tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -2 }` we extract all items but the last; `\tl_range:nnn { #1 } { -1 } { -1 }` extracts the last item.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\newcommand\abr[1]{\xintListWithSep{.\,}{#1}.}
\begin{document}
I've seen it in the \abr{OED}.

I got my \abr{{Ph}D}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Updated (à la Mico, but without LuaLaTeX)

The syntax here is to use `\abr{PhD.}` for example at end of a sentence, and `\abr{PhD}` if not at end of a sentence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\abr[1]
   {\expandafter\@gobbletwo\romannumeral0\xintapplyunbraced\abr@aux{#1}.\@}
\def\abr@sep{.\,}
\def\abr@aux#1{\if.#1\expandafter\abr@end
               \else
                \if1\ifnum`#1<`A 0\fi\ifnum`#1>`Z 0\fi1%
                   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\abr@sep
                \fi
               \fi#1}%
\def\abr@end.{ \abr@@end}
\def\abr@@end.\@{\@.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}%\ttfamily
I've seen it in the \abr{OED}, and if located at end of a sentence
just insert a dot in the \verb|\abr| argument: \abr{OED.} It ended a
sentence and in non-French spacing mode, TeX inserted the extra
space.

\texttt{We can see it better with monospace font: \abr{OED.} See?}

I got my \abr{PhD} and even my \abr{PhilD}, leniency ruled
in those days.

\texttt{The dots are added in a smart way: \abr{AaaaBbbbCccc.} But it is
assumed that the first letter is \abr{Uppercased.} That's it.}

\texttt{Notice that neitger \abr{Aaaa} nor \abr{AaA} trigger an end of
  sentence spacing after the dot, which is \abr{Good.} Isn't it?}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Again updated, for automatic end of sentence dot detection after abbreviation

Here an end of sentence dot will be detected automatically.

Of course we can't use `\@ifnextchar` for that, as it swallows spaces.

I added some comments about expandability, which seems to have drawn great attention in other answers `:)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortvrb}\MakeShortVerb{\|}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\abrsep{.\,}% maybe redefined even after \edef\foo{\abr{DPhil}}...
\protected\def\abrend{\futurelet\@let@token\abr@end}
\def\abr@end{\ifx.\@let@token\@\else.\@\fi}
\newcommand\abr[1]
   {\expandafter\@gobble\romannumeral0\xintapplyunbraced\abr@aux{#1}\abrend}
\def\abr@aux#1{\if1\ifnum`#1<`A 0\fi\ifnum`#1>`Z 0\fi1%
                   \expandafter\abr@sep
               \fi#1}%
\def\abr@sep{ \abrsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}%\ttfamily
I've seen it in the \abr{OED}, and if located at end of a sentence
it will detect it automatically: \abr{OED}. There was no double dot.
Besides, TeX applied its end of sentence extra space.

\texttt{We can see it better with monospace font: \abr{OED}. See?}

\texttt{We can see it better with monospace font: \abr{OED}, See?}

I got a \abr{MSc}, a \abr{PhD} and even a \abr{DPhil}. Leniency ruled
in those days. 

{The abbreviation dots are added in a smart way, after the last
  lowercase letter following an uppercase letter:
  \abr{AaaaBbbbCccc}. But it is \emph{assumed} that the first letter is
  \abr{Uppercased}. That's it.}

\texttt{Notice that neither \abr{DPhil} nor \abr{PhilD} get \TeX\ to
  consider the inserted final dot as signaling  an end of
  sentence spacing after the dot, which is \abr{Good}. Isn't it?}

About expandability, the correct way for \LaTeX2e's users would be to use
|\protected@edef|, not a naked |\edef|; although nowadays some
\LaTeX2e\ users have heard about |\edef|, they might not know
about |\protected@edef|, which requires a cumbersome extra
|\makeatletter| for its usage. Anyway, none of that is described in
\textsc{Lamport} book, so I wonder if \LaTeX2e users are really
\emph{allowed} into using |\edef| to start with.

But as it seems they know about |\edef|, we as macro programmers need
better to use the e-\TeX's |\protected| prefix and not the \LaTeX2e
|\DeclareRobustCommand|, because users will not do |\protected@edef|.

This is what I have done here for a macro |\abrsep| (why haven't we all
used |\abbr| by the way?) which is deliberately |\protected|,
allowing it to be redefined at location of use, long after some macro
will have been defined via |\edef\foo{\abr{ABCDEFGH}}|.

\edef\foo{\abr{ABCDEFGH}}\texttt{\string\foo\ is \meaning\foo}

\edef\foo{\abr{AaaBccCcc}}\texttt{\string\foo\ is \meaning\foo}

The |\abrend| is also |\protected|, anyway as its expansion will be
context dependent (it detects if a dot follows), it had to not expand
in the |\edef|.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that my proposals v2 and v3 will work only with ascii uppercase letters, no diacritics.

Comment: @Mico I plagiarized your input syntax for end of sentence...

Comment: @Mico I have again updated as I read OP is pushing towards automatic dot detection. One can not use LaTeX `\@ifnextchar` which swallows spaces.

Comment: Outstanding! :-) Incidentally, I've gone ahead and deleted my earlier comments are they're no longer relevant, or even understandable, for readers of the current version of your answer.

Comment: (not to be told publicly: of course I could remove all usage of xinttools but where is the fun without it?) well, in fact usage of a an xinttools macro facilitates a fixed number of expansion steps to get final result, here 3 steps, I could reduce to 2 steps. But doesn't matter for an `\edef` and anyhow the tokens of the input are subjected to full-first expansion via `\ifnum` test etc...

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\abr[1]{\abraux#1..}
\def\abraux#1#2#3{%
  #1%
  \ifnum`#2>91\relax% we have a lowercase letter following
    \def\next{\abraux#2#3}%
  \else
    .\ifx.#2\def\next{\@}\else\,\def\next{\abraux#2#3}\fi
  \fi
  \next
}
\begin{document}
    Here is \abr{OED} abbreviation.

    Here is \abr{XO} abbreviation.

    Here is \abr{XOOED} abbreviation.

    \abr{MSc}  

    \abr{DPhil}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can your code be extended to handle the lazy/slovenly punctuation of `MSc` (correct: `M.\,Sc.`) and `DPhil` (correct: `D.\,Phil.`)?

Comment: Sure, if it is _not_ an uppercase letter then go the next char.